# How to pass as parameter an array of pointers to structure in c

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, structure

I'm trying to pass an array of pointers to structure as parameter, to modify it in a function and to to print the modified value in `main()`.

The code is:

```
#include "stdio.h"

typedef struct testStruct_s {
   int x;
   int y;
} testStruct;

typedef testStruct typeTab[4];

void modify(typeTab tab)
{
   printf("Before modification %d\n", tab[2].x);
   tab[2].x = 3;
   printf("Modified %d\n", tab[2].x);
}


int main()
{
   typeTab tab[4];
   tab[2]->x = 0;
   printf("First %d\n", tab[2]->x);
   modify(*tab);
   printf("Second %d\n", tab[2]->x);
   return 0;
}
```

And I got the following output:

```
First 0
Before modification 1719752944
Modify 3
Second 0
```

I don't know the way to get the correct value of `tab[2].x` in `modify()` and how to modify this value to print `tab[2]->x = 3` after.

For what I try to do, it is required to use the `typedef testStruct`.

Comment: There is no "array of pointers to structure" in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`typeTab` is already an array, so `typeTab tab[4]` declares an array of arrays.  This means `tab[2]->x` is the same as `tab[2][0].x`, which is not what you want.

Don't add the extra dimension, then modify the access accordingly.

```
typeTab tab;

tab[2].x = 0;
printf("First %d\n", tab[2].x);
modify(tab);
printf("Second %d\n", tab[2].x);
```

Comment: @user10675921 Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.